# How to programmatically load a form for a given node, modify it's values and then submit it?

Tags: drupal-7

when I click on the "edit" tab of one of my forum nodes, I get a form displayed such as this:

[image: Edit view of a forum node]

When I select any option in the "Forums"-drop-down-menu (and thus choose a forum container) and click on "Submit", the forum node gets moved to the chosen forum container.

Now, what I need to do is to trigger all this programmatically from somewhere in my code. I have to move a lot of forum nodes to a lot of different forum containers, that's why I need to do this that way.

What I was thinking about how this could be done is this:

1. Load the form data of the "forum_node_form" so that the data of a specific forum node is included (the forum node I'd like to move to another forum container).
2. Change the parameter $form_state['values']['forum_tid'] to the tid of the forum container I'd like to move the forum node to.
3. Save the form data by using drupal_form_submit().

However, this proves to be harder than I expected. Can someone point out for me what's the right way to do this?

So far, I've logged the content of $form_state['values'] during a manual test using var_export($form_state['values'], true). I've then changed $form_state['values']['forum_tid'] to the tid of the forum container I'd like to move the forum to and then submitted the data using drupal_form_submit('forum_node_form', $form_state);

That led to the error message:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 795 of /"PATH"/includes/form.inc).

I've found some advice to use form_load_include() and therefore added this line:

`form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');`

...which leads to some new errors:

> - Warning: Missing argument 3 for node_form() in node_form() (line 83 of /"PATH"/modules/node/node.pages.inc).
> - EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7539 of /"PATH"/includes/common.inc).

Argument 3 of node_form() is the node object $node and I don't know how to solve this problem and I actually feel that this is not the right way to solve the whole issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through the pain of loading the node form, you can just load the node object (using [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7)), change the forum tid value, and save the node (using [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)) to update it.

Example:

```
<?php

function mymodule_updatemynode($nid,$new_forum_tid){
    if ($node = node_load($nid)){
        // not exactly sure what the forum tid field is called
        // just an example
        $node->field_forum_tid['und'][0]['#value'] = $new_forum_tid;
        node_save($node);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't do it. When I access the node after updating its forum_tid, the navigation bar shows "Home › Forums › General discussions", which is a good sign, since "General discussion" corresponds to the forum_tid I've assigned. But when I browse through the forums, this forum node doesn't show up. "General discussion" is listed with 0 topics and 0 posts. When I open the "General discussions"-forum, it's empty. Once I click the "edit"-tab of the forum node, choose the "General discussions"-forum from the drop-down-menu and click on "save", the forum nodes gets correctly assigned.

Comment: After further studying the content of $node and the way the taxonomy data of the forums are stored, I found out that the array "$node->taxonomy_forums" is responsible for the correct integration into the forum structure (in conjunction with $node->forum_tid). Thanks for your help, mmiles.